# Transform $2^{2\log n}$, given that $\log$ is base 10, to $n^{2/\log_2 10}$

Tags: logarithms

Can anyone show me the step by step transformation? This is the answer given in a class but I'm getting tripped up over here. Thank you.

Comment: What did you try? Where exactly did you get stuck? It's a straightforward application of logarithm properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
\begin{eqnarray}
n^{\frac{2}{\log_{2}{10}}}&=&n^{\frac{\log_{2} 2^2}{\log_{2}{10}}}=n^{\log 2^2}=2^{\log_{2}{n^{\log 2^2}}}=2^{\log 2^2\log_2{n}}=2^{2\log 2\log_2{n}}=2^{2\log 2\frac{\log{n}}{\log 2}}=2^{2\log{n}}
\end{eqnarray}